# Double sided input slider in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

**I have an almost working solution in the sandbox linked in the update below, you should start with this.**

---

I have one that's created without using React (Click "Run Code Snippet")

```js
var thumbsize = 14;

function draw(slider,splitvalue) {

    /* set function vars */
    var min = slider.querySelector('.min');
    var max = slider.querySelector('.max');
    var thumbsize = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-thumbsize'));
    var rangewidth = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-rangewidth'));
    var rangemin = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-rangemin'));
    var rangemax = parseInt(slider.getAttribute('data-rangemax'));

    /* set min and max attributes */
    min.setAttribute('max',splitvalue);
    max.setAttribute('min',splitvalue);

    /* set css */
    min.style.width = parseInt(thumbsize + ((splitvalue - rangemin)/(rangemax - rangemin))*(rangewidth - (2*thumbsize)))+'px';
    max.style.width = parseInt(thumbsize + ((rangemax - splitvalue)/(rangemax - rangemin))*(rangewidth - (2*thumbsize)))+'px';
    min.style.left = '0px';
    max.style.left = parseInt(min.style.width)+'px';
    
    /* correct for 1 off at the end */
    if(max.value>(rangemax - 1)) max.setAttribute('data-value',rangemax);

    /* write value and labels */
    max.value = max.getAttribute('data-value'); 
    min.value = min.getAttribute('data-value');

}

function init(slider) {
    /* set function vars */
    var min = slider.querySelector('.min');
    var max = slider.querySelector('.max');
    var rangemin = parseInt(min.getAttribute('min'));
    var rangemax = parseInt(max.getAttribute('max'));
    var avgvalue = (rangemin + rangemax)/2;

    /* set data-values */
    min.setAttribute('data-value',rangemin);
    max.setAttribute('data-value',rangemax);
    
    /* set data vars */
    slider.setAttribute('data-rangemin',rangemin); 
    slider.setAttribute('data-rangemax',rangemax); 
    slider.setAttribute('data-thumbsize',thumbsize); 
    slider.setAttribute('data-rangewidth',slider.offsetWidth);

    /* draw */
    draw(slider,avgvalue);

    /* events */
    min.addEventListener("input", function() {update(min);});
    max.addEventListener("input", function() {update(max);});
}

function update(el){
    /* set function vars */
    var slider = el.parentElement;
    var min = slider.querySelector('#min');
    var max = slider.querySelector('#max');
    var minvalue = Math.floor(min.value);
    var maxvalue = Math.floor(max.value);
    
    /* set inactive values before draw */
    min.setAttribute('data-value',minvalue);
    max.setAttribute('data-value',maxvalue);

    var avgvalue = (minvalue + maxvalue)/2;

    /* draw */
    draw(slider,avgvalue);
}

var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.min-max-slider');
sliders.forEach( function(slider) {
    init(slider);
});
```

```css
.min-max-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }

.min-max-slider > label {
  display: none;
 }
 
.min-max-slider > input {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}


/* webkit specific styling */
.min-max-slider > input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none!important;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 30%, silver 30%, silver 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
}

.min-max-slider > input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 14px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 14px; /* Slider handle height */
  background: #eee; /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.min-max-slider > input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="min-max-slider" data-legendnum="2">
    <label for="min">Minimum price</label>
    <input id="min" class="min" name="min" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="3000" />
    <label for="max">Maximum price</label>
    <input id="max" class="max" name="max" type="range" step="1" min="0" max="3000" />
</div>
```

I've tried to create the same sort of component using React. But each thumbgrip can only slide to the mid-point, where as with the non-react example, the lesser slider simply can't be higher than the higher slider and vice versa.

I would also like some way to make the slider which outside the range of the thumbgrips a darker color.

```js
var thumbsize = 14;

const Slider = ({min, max}) => {
    const avg = (min + max)/2;
  const width = 300
  const minWidth = thumbsize + ((avg - min)/(max - min))*(width - (2*thumbsize))
  const styles={
      min:{
        width: minWidth,
        left: 0
      },
      max:{
        width: thumbsize + ((max - avg)/(max - min))*(width - (2*thumbsize)),
        left: minWidth
      }
  }
  
    return (
    <div 
      class="min-max-slider"
      data-legendnum="2"
      data-rangemin={min}
      data-rangemax={max}
      data-thumbsize={thumbsize}
      data-rangewidth={width}
    >
      <label htmlFor="min">Minimum price</label>
      <input 
        id="min"
        className="min"
        style={styles.min}
        name="min"
        type="range"
        step="1"
        min={min}
        max={avg}
        data-value={min}
       />
      <label htmlFor="max">Maximum price</label>
      <input
        id="max"
        className="max"
        style={styles.max}
        name="max"
        type="range"
        step="1"
        min={avg}
        max={max}
        data-value={max}
       />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Slider min={300} max={3000} />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```css
 



.min-max-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }

.min-max-slider > label {
  display: none;
 }
 
.min-max-slider > input {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}


/* webkit specific styling */
.min-max-slider > input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none!important;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 30%, silver 30%, silver 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
}

.min-max-slider > input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
  appearance: none;
  width: 14px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
  height: 14px; /* Slider handle height */
  background: #eee; /* Green background */
  cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.min-max-slider > input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Using lissetdm's solution below, I have been able to create a double sided slider, which you can view on [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-double-slider-with-colors-and-labels-forked-lksx1?file=/src/styles.css), but there are still a few problems with it.

1. The orange doesn't always look like it overlaps the gray

[image]

Sometimes, unpredictably, this difference is very noticeable

[image]
[image]

2. When both thumb pieces are dragged to the edges, the one pushes the other down

[image]

3. I can't seem to remove this outline, which doesn't always appear

[image]

---

I have tested this out in **firefox**

Comment: In Google Chrome it has different style. Should it be orange color on the middle and grey color on the sides?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As react works, you need to move avg to the component's state and during input onChange event update it's value:

```
const Slider = ({ min, max }) => {
  const [avg, setAvg] = useState((min + max) / 2);
  const [minVal, setMinVal] = useState(avg);
  const [maxVal, setMaxVal] = useState(avg);

  const width = 300;
  const minWidth =
    thumbsize + ((avg - min) / (max - min)) * (width - 2 * thumbsize);
  const styles = {
    min: {
      width: minWidth,
      left: 0
    },
    max: {
      width: thumbsize + ((max - avg) / (max - min)) * (width - 2 * thumbsize),
      left: minWidth
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setAvg((maxVal + minVal) / 2);
  }, [minVal, maxVal]);


  return (
    <div
      className="min-max-slider"
      data-legendnum="2"
      data-rangemin={min}
      data-rangemax={max}
      data-thumbsize={thumbsize}
      data-rangewidth={width}
    >
      <label htmlFor="min">Minimum price</label>
      <input
        id="min"
        className="min"
        style={styles.min}
        name="min"
        type="range"
        step="1"
        min={min}
        max={avg}
        value={minVal}
        onChange={({ target }) => setMinVal(Number(target.value))}
      />
      <label htmlFor="max">Maximum price</label>
      <input
        id="max"
        className="max"
        style={styles.max}
        name="max"
        type="range"
        step="1"
        min={avg}
        max={max}
        value={maxVal}
        onChange={({ target }) => setMaxVal(Number(target.value))}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### UPDATED

> I can't seem to remove this outline, which doesn't always appear

This line appears because the browser detects that the input is invalid. To disable this effect use:

```
input[type="range"]:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

> The orange doesn't always look like it overlaps the gray

And

> When both thumb pieces are dragged to the edges, the one pushes the
> other down

I can't reproduce this scenarios but I recommend you to control the background color using the min and max position:

CSS:

```
input[type="range"] {
  --minRangePercent: 0%;
  --maxRangePercent: 0%;
  height: .4rem;
}

.min-max-slider > input.min {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    silver 0%,
    silver var(--minRangePercent),
    orange var(--minRangePercent),
    orange 100%
  );
}

.min-max-slider > input.max {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    orange 0%,
    orange var(--maxRangePercent),
    silver var(--maxRangePercent),
    silver 100%
  );
}
```

JS:

```
const minPercent = ((minVal - min) / (avg - min)) * 100;
const maxPercent = ((maxVal - avg) / (max - avg)) * 100;
const styles = {
    min: {
      width: minWidth,
      left: 0,
      "--minRangePercent": `${minPercent}%`
    },
    max: {
      width: thumbsize + ((max - avg) / (max - min)) * (width - 2 * thumbsize),
      left: minWidth,
      "--maxRangePercent": `${maxPercent}%`
    }
 };
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-double-slider-with-colors-and-labels-forked-stt73?file=/src/App.js:404-806)

Comment: I put your slider in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-agnesi-mldkf?file=/src/App.js) and it's finicky, and also both thumb pieces still have a min and max

Comment: Yes, I see it has different behavior depending on browser, I added property value to avoid this. see: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-silence-dt73v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I noticed another bug, sorry, when you stretch the thumb pieces to their minimum and maximum values, one of them becomes inactive

Comment: Oh don't worry the idea is that it works fine, I updated the code, I think it looks better now, https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-silence-dt73v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Perfect. And the code on that sandbox matches the code in your answer?

Comment: [I updated the slider to include custom coloring for progress](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-double-slider-with-colors-and-labels-mfbt5?file=/src/App.js), but it looks a little misaligned and I can't remove that red outline on the right slider. Do you know whats wrong? Tested it in Firefox

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer https://codesandbox.io/s/react-double-slider-with-colors-and-labels-forked-stt73?file=/src/App.js:404-806

Comment: Do you know why the knobs are blue in chrome?

Comment: That is because the style is not apply, for some reason it detects something wrong, you can fix it dividing this input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb,
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb { in two different blocks, and you will see the styles applied

Comment: It is not related to the question but I recommend you to use some debounce function to avoid many renderings from the component. If you move the slider 1000 positions, it will cause 1000 renderings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `min` and `max` are strings so calculating the `avg` was incorrect but by using `parseInt` you will get integers as expected. [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dijkstra-9p7jb?file=/src/App.js) i created a sandbox but i had to change the value of `width` from `30` to `300` to make enough space for the dots.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that, but there was another problem, that each thumbpiece could only slide to the middle. If you look at the plain javascript example that doesn't happen